# newbie attempt to use Java ArrayList to store ResultSet obtained from database

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a database server communicating with a Java application server using JDBC. I want to store data from the database ResultSet into Java variables.

Here's my Java class, HRPeople:

```
public class HRPeople {
    public int elements;
    public String[] FirstName;
    public String[] LastName;
    public String[] Email;
    public int[] Salary;
}
```

I currently use this class to store data from ResultSet, as follows:

```
query = "SELECT first_name, last_name, email, salary FROM HR.Employees where rownum < 6";
rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);
while (rset.next()) {
    returnHRdata.FirstName[ii] = rset.getString("first_name");
    returnHRdata.LastName[ii]  = rset.getString("last_name");
    returnHRdata.Email[ii]     = rset.getString("email");
    returnHRdata.Salary[ii]    = rset.getInt("salary");
    ii = ii + 1;
}
```

The problem with the above scenario is that the primitive arrays require me to know the number of rows in the ResultSet so that I can properly initialize those arrays. So what I want to do is use an ArrayList instead. How would I modify the above scenario to do this?

Here's my initial attempt (is this close)? Is HRPeople.java file shown above even used in this scenario?

```
query = "SELECT first_name, last_name, email, salary FROM HR.Employees where rownum < 6";
rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);
List<HRPeople> returnHRdata = new ArrayList<HRPeople>();
while (rset.next()) {
   returnHRdata.FirstName = rset.getString("first_name");
   returnHRdata.LastName  = rset.getString("last_name");
   returnHRdata.Email     = rset.getString("email");
   returnHRdata.Salary    = rset.getInt("salary");
   returnHRdata.add;
}
```

UPDATE 1:

If I add to the code the following,

```
return returnHRdata;
```

I get the following error (any idea why?):

```
myClass.java:213: incompatible types
found   : java.util.List<HRPerson>
required: java.util.ArrayList<HRPerson>
    return returnHRdata;
           ^
1 error
```

Comment: The maximum salary is only $2,147,483,647?!

Comment: @Ryan actually maximum is 2,147,483,647 currency units. In Korea, that is "only" $ 2 millions!

Comment: @assylias oh snap! better optimize for hyperinflation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to first define an HRPerson like this:

```
public class HRPerson {
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String email;
    public int salary;
}
```

Then your main code would look like:

```
query = "SELECT first_name, last_name, email, salary FROM HR.Employees where rownum < 6";
rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);
List<HRPerson> returnHRdata = new ArrayList<HRPerson>();
while (rset.next()) {
   HRPerson person = new HRPerson();
   person.firstName = rset.getString("first_name");
   person.lastName  = rset.getString("last_name");
   person.email     = rset.getString("email");
   person.salary    = rset.getInt("salary");
   returnHRdata.add(person);
}
```

Comment: Looks good. When I add a `return returnHRdata;` it gives a compile error (see UPDATE 1 above). Any idea why?

Comment: I assume your method is declared as public ArrayList<HRPerson> yourMethod(args) {...}. In which case you need to change it to public List<HRPerson> yourMethod(args) {...}

Answer (score 1):

```
List<HRPeople> returnHRdata = new ArrayList<HRPeople>();
while (rset.next()) {
   HRPeople people = new HRPeople();
   people.FirstName = rset.getString("first_name");
   people.LastName = rset.getString("last_name");
   people.Email    = rset.getString("email");
   people.Salary    = rset.getInt("salary");
   returnHRdata.add(people);
}
```

You can improve this code by using a lowerCase letter for your first char of your fields and using getters and setters to access them.

Comment: Oh  my, yes I did not even see that HRPeople was using arrays. Of course the implementation of HRPeople shown below is mandatory.

Comment: Good point to the getter/setter and syntax cases, but he'd have to change the class for this solution, change it from using the arrays in `HRPeople` to simply `String`s and `int`. Which you mentioned just as I typed this... :)

Answer (score 1):

Convert this:

```
public class HRPeople {
  public int elements;
    public String[] FirstName;
    public String[] LastName;
    public String[] Email;
    public int[] Salary;
}
```

to:

```
public class HRPerson {
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String email;
    public int salary;
}
```

and:

```
List<HRPerson> people = new ArrayList<HRPerson>();
```

Now it should be easy:

```
while (rset.next()) {
  HRPerson person = new HRPerson();
  returnHRdata.firstName = rset.getString("first_name");
  returnHRdata.lastName = rset.getString("last_name");
  returnHRdata.email = rset.getString("email");
  returnHRdata.salary = rset.getInt("salary");
  people.add(person);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Close...

```
while (rset.next()) {
   HRPeople person = new HRPeople();
   person.setFirstName(rset.getString("first_name"));
   person.setLastName(rset.getString("last_name"));
   person.setEmail(rset.getString("email"));
   person.setSalary(rset.getInt("salary"));
   returnHRdata.add(person);
}
```

You of course must define the setXXXX methods on the HRPerson class.  Oh yeah, and do what Thomasz suggested.

Answer (score 0):

create a class HRPeople, which has firstname, lastname.... attributes, and declare getter, setters method.

then:

```
List<HRPeople> returnHRdata = new ArrayList<HRPeople>();
HRPeople people = null;
while (rset.next()) {
   people = new HRPeople();
   people.setFirstName( rset.getString("first_name"));
   people.setLastName (rset.getString("last_name"));
...
   returnHRdata.add(people);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing an array of each property in your object, make a single object to describe a given entity in the table.

```
class HRPerson {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String email;
    Integer salary;
}
```

Create a list of this type, allowing you to store the results.

```
List<HRPerson> hrPeople = new ArrayList<HRPerson>();

while(rset.next()) {
    HRPerson person = new HRPerson();
    person.firstName = rset.getString("first_name");
    person.lastName  = rset.getString("last_name");
    person.email     = rset.getString("email");
    person.salary    = rset.getInt("salary");

    hrPeople.add(person);
}
```

Finally, fill it by creating new objects for each row in your table.