# storing and using arraylist data returned from list<variables> function

Tags: java, function, arraylist

hi im trying to store data returned from a database so i can use it in my application, after finding [newbie attempt to use Java ArrayList to store ResultSet obtained from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585764/newbie-attempt-to-use-java-arraylist-to-store-resultset-obtained-from-database) i made the following code which seems to work fine;

code for stordetails:

```
public class StoryDetails {
  public int id;
  public String genre;
  public String category;
  public String title;
  public int chapters;
  public int current;
  public Date checked;
}
```

code for stroring the data:

```
    List<StoryDetails> storyData = new ArrayList<StoryDetails>();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            StoryDetails story = new StoryDetails();
            story.id        = resultSet.getInt("ID");
            story.genre     = resultSet.getString("GENRE");
            story.category  = resultSet.getString("CATEGORY");
            story.title     = resultSet.getString("TITLE");
            story.chapters  = resultSet.getInt("CHAPTERS");
            story.current   = resultSet.getInt("CURRENT");
            story.checked   = resultSet.getDate("CHECKED");
            storyData.add(story);
        }
        return storyData;
```

the problem im having is i cant figure how to store and use the data thats returned from this. any help is appreciated.

i currently have

```
List<StoryDetails> list = dao.displayAll(query);
     for(StoryDetails obj : list){
         System.out.println(String.valueOf(obj[0]));
     }
```

but it doesnt work.

the answer turned out to be:

```
     List<StoryDetails> list = dao.displayAll(query);
     //for all
     for(StoryDetails obj : list){
         System.out.println(obj.id);
         System.out.println(obj.category);
     }
     //for specific
     System.out.println(list.get(0).category);
```

Comment: You have a List containing your data, what more would you need ?

Comment: im not sure if im missing something obvious or your just trolling as to me this isnt exactly a normal list

Comment: What is `dao.displayAll(query)`? Does that run the code that has `storyData` being populated?

Comment: @Epic-jargon : I'm not trolling. Why do you say this is not a normal list ? Seems totally normal to me. Your loop is really weird... You are trying to use `StoryDetails` instances as if it were arrays. Why ?

Comment: @Dici im aware of how to access lists but because im using instantiated variables i was at a loss of how to access them i found some documentation that pointed me to the above ive since found the problem as what i needed was list.get(0).category. its simple but i couldnt find much help which is why i asked on here

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are trying to use your `StoryDetails` objects as arrays but here is what you should do :

```
for(StoryDetails sd : dao.displayAll(query))
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(sd));
```

Comment: this doesnt work i get other.StoryDetails@ac8360
other.StoryDetails@1e534cb
etc

Comment: It works, this simply means that you didn't override toString() in this class. What are you actually trying to do ?

Comment: i was trying to display the data within the list that was populated from the resultset, ive managed to do it now and have put the answer at the bottom of my question

Comment: Well you were wondering how to access the attributes of an object ? You could have say it that way since the beginning :)